# Can not install node-sass to React project

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I want to add `node-sass` to my react projects. This is something `Pyhton` error.  How can I fix this ?
I have tried to update or downgrade node but did not know which version is suitable.
Also, tried to re-install `node-gyp` but still not working.
What is the problem with that ?

node-version : `14.15.0`
npm version: `6.14.8`

```
    error C:\Users\hasan\Desktop\modabu-react\node_modules\node-sass: Command failed.
    Exit code: 1
    Command: node scripts/build.js
    Arguments:
    Directory: C:\Users\hasan\Desktop\modabu-react\node_modules\node-sass
    Output:
    Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\hasan\Desktop\modabu-react\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
    gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
    gyp verb cli [
    gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
    gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\hasan\\Desktop\\modabu-react\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
    gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
    gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
    gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
    gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
    gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
    gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
    gyp verb cli ]
    gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
    gyp info using node@14.15.0 | win32 | x64
    gyp verb command rebuild []
    gyp verb command clean []
    gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
    gyp verb command configure []
    gyp verb find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
    gyp verb find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
    gyp verb find Python checking if "python3" can be used
    gyp verb find Python - executing "python3" to get executable path
    gyp verb find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
    gyp verb find Python checking if "python" can be used
    gyp verb find Python - executing "python" to get executable path
    gyp verb find Python - "python" is not in PATH or produced an error
    gyp verb find Python checking if "python2" can be used
    gyp verb find Python - executing "python2" to get executable path
    gyp verb find Python - "python2" is not in PATH or produced an error
    gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Python37\python.exe
    gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Python37\python.exe" to get version
    gyp verb find Python - "C:\Python37\python.exe" could not be run
    gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Python27\python.exe
    gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Python27\python.exe" to get version
    gyp verb find Python - "C:\Python27\python.exe" could not be run
    gyp verb find Python checking if the py launcher can be used to find Python
    gyp verb find Python - executing "py.exe" to get Python executable path
    gyp verb find Python - "py.exe" is not in PATH or produced an error
    gyp ERR! find Python
    gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
    gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
    gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python3" can be used
    gyp ERR! find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
    gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python" can be used
    gyp ERR! find Python - "python" is not in PATH or produced an error
    gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python2" can be used
    gyp ERR! find Python - "python2" is not in PATH or produced an error
    gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Python37\python.exe
    gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Python37\python.exe" could not be run
    gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Python27\python.exe
    gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Python27\python.exe" could not be run
    gyp ERR! find Python checking if the py launcher can be used to find Python
    gyp ERR! find Python - "py.exe" is not in PATH or produced an error
    gyp ERR! find Python
    gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
    gyp ERR! find Python You need to install the latest version of Python.
    gyp ERR! find Python Node-gyp should be able to find and use Python. If not,
    gyp ERR! find Python you can try one of the following options:
    gyp ERR! find Python - Use the switch --python="C:\Path\To\python.exe"
    gyp ERR! find Python   (accepted by both node-gyp and npm)
    gyp ERR! find Python - Set the environment variable PYTHON
    gyp ERR! find Python - Set the npm configuration variable python:
    gyp ERR! find Python   npm config set python "C:\Path\To\python.exe"
    gyp ERR! find Python For more information consult the documentation at:
    gyp ERR! find Python https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation
    gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
    gyp ERR! find Python
    gyp ERR! configure error
    gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Python installation to use
    gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.fail (C:\Users\hasan\Desktop\modabu-react\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:302:47)
    gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.runChecks (C:\Users\hasan\Desktop\modabu-react\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:136:21)
    gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Users\hasan\Desktop\modabu-react\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:200:18)       
    gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.execFileCallback (C:\Users\hasan\Desktop\modabu-react\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:266:16)  
    gyp ERR! stack     at exithandler (child_process.js:315:5)
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.errorhandler (child_process.js:327:5)
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
    gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
    gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:465:16)
    gyp ERR! stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
    gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19041
    gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\hasan\\Desktop\\modabu-react\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" 
    "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
    gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\hasan\Desktop\modabu-react\node_modules\node-sass
    gyp ERR! node -v v14.15.0
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear: `Error: Could not find any Python installation to use`. Have you installed Python2 or Python3 on that machine? If not: https://www.python.org/downloads/

Comment: Hi @ChrisG am I need to install latest version ?

Comment: Yeah, best use the latest version of Python 3. Installing it should append the binary location to PATH, which means that in the command line, you should be able to simply type `python --version` and see the installed version. Once that works, try installing the node modules again.

Comment: @ChrisG
`gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Users\hasan\Desktop\modabu-react\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:121:47)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\hasan\Desktop\modabu-react\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:74:16
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Users\hasan\Desktop\modabu-react\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:351:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\hasan\Desktop\modabu-react\node_modules\node-

Comment: Ok... [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=Could+not+find+any+Visual+Studio+installation+to+use+gyp) the main error message and look for existing solutions

Comment: @ChrisG now, I guess it needs Visual Studio installation. `Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use gyp ERR`